# How do you specify a policy name when creating a new role?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I'm converting some aws-iot java code over to use boto3 and am stuck when creating a new role. The old code specifies a policy name when specifying the policy for a role, but I don't know how to specify that in boto3. Here's the java code block (note: withId(assumePolicyName)):

```
iamClient.createRole(new CreateRoleRequest()
                .withRoleName(role)
                .withAssumeRolePolicyDocument(new com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Policy()
                    .withId(assumePolicyName)
                    .withStatements(new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
                        .withActions(() -> "sts:AssumeRole")
                        .withPrincipals(new Principal("Service", "iot.amazonaws.com")))
                    .toJson()
                )
            );
```

I can't figure out where to specify the assumePolicyName with boto3, here's what I have in boto3:

```
self.iamClient.create_role(RoleName=role_name, AssumeRolePolicyDocument={
            'Statement': [
                {
                    'Principal': {
                        'Service': ['iot.amazonaws.com']
                    },
                    'Effect': 'Allow',
                    'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole']
                },
            ]
        }
```

How do I specify a policy name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty close. I should have just attempted a few trial/errors. The correct solution is this document:

```
self.iamClient.create_role(RoleName=role_name, AssumeRolePolicyDocument={
                'Id': 'assume_role_id',
                'Statement': [
                {
                    'Principal': {
                        'Service': ['iot.amazonaws.com']
                    },
                    'Effect': 'Allow',
                    'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole']
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IAM provides no way to associate a policy name with the `AssumedRolePolicyDocument`.  I'm not sure what purpose a name would serve since there can be only one such policy per role and these trust relationships cannot be shared between roles.